# How to publish scientific papers on the internet for free?

Tags: soft-question

I have written some scientific papers and I want to publish them for free so peoples can take benefit from it and I also want to make it safe so no one can steal it.

PS: I am very young and I don't have the necessary amount of money.

Comment: post them on http://vixra.org/

Comment: What are your papers about?

Comment: It's possible that this may be on-topic for [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Since this is back on top of the pile, I think the migration to a.se is desirable if they will have it.